# How to test DoS attack by sending unsolicited ARP packets over ethernet?

Tags: nmap, arp

I want to test a system for DoS attack using ARP packets as the system only responds to ARP packets and left all ports are closed.

Can nmap or arping help in this case?

Comment: What you are looking for is 'ARP Storm'. You can accomplish this via Python libraries such as; Scapy, nmap ex. A little script which produces ARP requests constantly (in a loop) with multi-threading to the target machine. Important links can help are following: http://www.scirp.org/JOURNAL/PaperInformation.aspx?PaperID=2962            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804176/python-scapy-arp-request-and-response                                                                                                      https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-nmap

Answer (score 2):

I uploaded an old python script of mine [right here.](https://github.com/b-bellecour/arp-flooder)
This piece of code is very basic and clearly not a masterpiece, it just answered my needs few years ago.

I recommend you to look and understand how its done, then build your own tool.

I'm not sure this old lazy script still work, but you can get the idea of how you can use the scapy lib.